# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in call to CFSocketSendData

Tags: objective-c, sockets

I am using an instance of the this class to pass necessary values to a function for sending Socket Data:

```
@interface SsdpParameters : NSObject
{
    CFDataRef msg;
    CFDataRef addr;
    CFSocketRef sock;
}

@property CFDataRef msg;
@property CFDataRef addr;
@property CFSocketRef sock;

@end
```

This is the function that is responsible for sending the socket data:

```
-(void)SendSsdpResponse:(id)parameters
{
    SsdpParameters *params = parameters;
    CFDataRef msg = (CFDataRef)params.msg;
    CFDataRef addr = (CFDataRef)params.addr;
    CFSocketRef sock = (CFSocketRef)params.sock;

    CFSocketError err = CFSocketSendData (sock, addr, msg, 0);  // Program received signal:  "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

    if (err)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error sending Valid Response");
    }
}
```

This function sets up the socket and calls SendSsdpResponse after a 1 second delay:

```
- (void) sendValidResponses
{
    NSMutableString *message = nil;
CFSocketRef sock = [self newSSDPSendSocket];
if(sock != nil)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in SSDPaddr;
        memset(&SSDPaddr, 0, sizeof(SSDPaddr));
        SSDPaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        SSDPaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(SSDP_ADDRESS);
        SSDPaddr.sin_port=htons(SSDP_PORT);

        // Loop through list, sending SSDP
        for (NSString *aKey in list)
        {
            message = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1\r\n"];

        // Append more lines to message.

            CFDataRef addr = CFDataCreate(NULL, (const UInt8*)&SSDPaddr, sizeof(SSDPaddr));
            CFDataRef msg  = CFDataCreate(NULL, (const UInt8*)[message UTF8String], [message lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

            SsdpParameters *parameters = [[SsdpParameters alloc] init];
            parameters.msg = msg;
            parameters.addr = addr;
            parameters.sock = sock;

            [self performSelector:@selector(SendSsdpResponse:) withObject:parameters afterDelay:1.0];

            CFRelease(addr);
            CFRelease(msg);
            [message release];
        }

        CFRelease(sock);
    }
}
```

As you can see by the comment, in SendSsdpResponse, I an getting a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error when trying to call CFSendSocketData.  I have a suspicion that it's because I am "passing" `sock`, `addr`, and `msg` and there is something the runtime does not like about this.  I have run into this problem before with passing variables of the CF data types to other functions.  I have yet to find an answer and hope someone here can finally help me understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors generally indicate that you're attempting to invoke a method on an instance that has already been deallocated. This is often the case when you fail to properly `retain` variables, especially when they're being passed between functions.

When you perform the selector with the delay, on this line:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(SendSsdpResponse:) withObject:parameters afterDelay:1.0];
```

You're providing the method with the `parameters` variable, which has the properties as defined in the header you provided. The problem is that right after the `performSelector:` method, you're releasing the memory referred to `addr` and `msg`. Since you're performing this selector with a delay, **the memory that addr and msg point to is being deallocated prior to its use**.

So, once this memory has been released, it is no longer "good" in the `SsdpParameters` object. You should (in the setter for these properties, on the `SsdpParameters` object) copy this memory, so that the original callers can release it safely.

You should investigate this function:

```
CFDataRef CFDataCreateCopy (
   CFAllocatorRef allocator,
   CFDataRef theData
);
```

Then, your setter could look like:

```
@implementation SsdpParameters

...

- (void)setMsg:(CFDataRef)m {
    // You should also release msg if it already exists
    msg = CFDataCreateCopy(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), m);
}

...

@end
```

Comment: I must have been finding this solution just as you were typing it.  I foolishly thought that the app would block on the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay and the CFRelease calls would not run until after it was done executing.  I am still getting used to asynchronous programming and this is another example of how one can get bitten by it if the understanding is not there.  To get it to work, I moved the CFRelease calls to SendSsdpResponse, but I will definitely look into CFDataCreateCopy.

Comment: Ah, haha yea it can be a very tricky subject. I would strongly recommend checking out Grand Central Dispatch if you're going to be using asynchronous code, especially one-off, disposable tasks.

Comment: I just saw your new comments on the accessor, and your comment about releasing `msg` if it already exists.  I know CFRelease will do the releasing, but I am unsure how to check for existence.  I am using `if (msg) { CFRelease(msg); }` and it seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, try replacing the call to

```
[self performSelector:@selector(SendSsdpResponse:) withObject:parameters afterDelay:1.0];
```

with an immediate call to

```
[self SendSsdpResponse:parameters];
```

and see what happens.

If you still get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS", it means your parameters are set up incorrectly somehow. If, on the other hand, you don't get an error, it means that the parameter object is ok initially, but becomes invalid before the delay completes. For example, is the parameters object retaining or copying "addr" and "msg"?

Comment: Pretty close.  You were on the right track with mentioning the parameters.  Thanks for the response.